# How to throttle Camel context having two routes with file consumer and queue consumer

Tags: file, apache-camel, throttling

I have two routes:

1. polls files, processes and posts to a queue
2. takes the message from queue and processes

Both routes involve database updates. Currently we are using `maxMessagesPerPoll` as `1` and delay of `10` seconds on the 1st route as it takes around 5s for both routes to complete processing. But occasionally the 1st route's DB update processing interferes with the 2nd route's DB processing resulting in deadlock.

```xml
<route id="_route1">
    <from id="_fromFileLocation" uri="FileLocation?delay=10s"/>
    <process id="_process1" ref="processor1"/> <!-- processor posts message to the Q -->
</route>
<route id="_route2">
    <from id="_fromQueue" uri="activemq:queuelocation"/>
    <process id="_process2" ref="processor2"/>
</route>
```

If 1st route only takes a new file after 2nd route is completed, then there would be no issue. I have tried throttling policy with `maxInFlightExchanges` as `1` & scope as Context on 1st route but throttling kicks in only when there are 2 in flight messages in context and allows 1st route to poll new file as soon as there is only 1 in flight exchange in the context.

How can I ensure there is only 1 InFlight Exchange in the entire camel context? i.e. 1st route should only take another file when the 2nd route processing is completed. Thank you in advance.